# How does one set the temperature threshold for heatpump? Carrier Infinity

Tags: heat-pump, carrier

I've just had a Carrier Infinity heat pump installed, with the matching smart thermostat. The only problem with it is that while it has three settings for the heat source:

- Heat pump only
- Electric heat only
- System in control

There's nowhere to set the threshold temperature for electric heat. Where I live, you can have -30 celsius one day and 3 celsius the next day. Currently, system in control would still use heatpump at -30. Trying to pump heat with a 50 degree differential is not only inefficient, it also shortens the equipment lifespan. My previous thermostat, nest, would switch to auxillary heat below -6 celsius.

Reseller was supposed to tell me how to access the admin settings but doesn't ever get back to me. **Is there a general approach to figuring out where this setting is?** The thermostat UI doesn't seem to show it anywhere.

Data about what I've got installed:
(snippet from a french invoice, so apologies for my french)

```
25VNA036A003 HEATPUMP CARRIER INFINITY GREENSPEED 3
FE4ANF003L00 FAN COIL 2-3.5 TONNE VITESSE VARIABLE 1
KFCEH3201F20 ÉLÉMENT ÉLECTRIQUE 20 KW 1
SYSTXCCITC01-B THERMOSTAT INFINITY TOUCH WALL 1
```

(I can handle a voltmeter and I can also capture the network traffic of the device connecting to the infinity server, if this is of any help)

Comment: If your Touch Control unit looks anything like [this one](http://dms.hvacpartners.com/docs/1009/Public/05/SYSTXCCITW-03SI.pdf), then section 6.3.4.7 on page 34 tells you about a 'High Heat Latch' setting which is described as "This option sets the outside temperature below which only the high stage (of a
2--stage outdoor unit) will run when heating."

Comment: Also, you'll want to somehow verify that an outside temperature sensor was installed.  Mine was not installed, so I have to select my heat source more manually than I would like.

Comment: @brhans it would seem the heat and cool latch only apply to dual stage units. My units doesn't have them and thus the options are greyed out. However, the doc was super useful as it also have "Heat source lockouts", which seem to limit the heatpump heat/cool to operate above/below certain outside temperature.